# Mysql Join condition connecting two databases in the same server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
select first_name, last_name, amount, payment_date 
from customer_db.customer_data c
join employee_db.payment e
on c.customer_id= e.payment_id 
where customer_db.customer_data(customer_id)='6';
```

I am getting

```
12:05:54    select first_name, last_name, amount, payment_date  from customer_db.customer_data c join employee_db.payment e on c.customer_id= e.payment_id  where customer_db.customer_data(customer_id)='6' LIMIT 0, 1000
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION customer_db.customer_data does not exist 0.000 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to call a function:

```
where customer_db.customer_data(customer_id)='6';
                               ^-----------^
```

Perhaps you meant

```
where customer_db.customer_data.customer_id='6';
                               ^---
```

instead?

Comment: if I do like that then i get this error 12:14:28 select first_name, last_name, amount, payment_date  from customer_db.customer_data c join employee_db.payment e on c.customer_id= e.payment_id  where customer_db.customer_data.customer_id='6' LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'customer_db.customer_data.customer_id' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec

Comment: Customer_data is a table in customer_db and i am referring to customer_id column.

Comment: Then `c.customer_id` instead, since you aliased the table

Answer (score 0):

You use alias for table in your query so you must replace this:

```
customer_db.customer_data.customer_id
```

With

```
c.customer_id
```

Comment: I tried even that but i get this error 13:16:11 select first_name, last_name, amount, payment_date  from customer_db.customer_data c join employee_db.payment e on c.customer_id= e.payment_id  where c.customer_id='6' LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.customer_id' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_db.customer_data.first_name, customer_db.customer_data.last_name, employee_db.payment.amount, employee_db.payment.payment_date 
from customer_db.customer_data
inner join employee_db.payment
on customer_db.customer_data.customer_data_id = employee_db.payment.payment_id
where customer_db.customer_data.customer_data_id ='6';
```

I finally found the solution. Thannks